# Standard Deviation of image OpenCv4Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to calculate Standard Deviation of GRAYSCALE image. To do it I'm using this function:

```
MatOfDouble mean = new MatOfDouble();
MatOfDouble std = new MatOfDouble();

Core.meanStdDev(image, mean, std);
```

According to documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#meanStdDev(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.MatOfDouble,org.opencv.core.MatOfDouble)

I'm getting

mean - output parameter: calculated mean value 
stddev - output parameter: calculateded standard deviation

But mean and stddev are both matrix. How can I get single double value from it?

Comment: haven't tried, but knowing it's a cv::Scalar in c++, try : double[] val = mean.get(0,0)

Comment: it worked like mean.toArray()[0]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting OpenCV code from C++ to Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636403/converting-opencv-code-from-c-to-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get standard deviation

```
std.toArray()[0]
```